# Excluding values in cross table

Tags: r, dataset, chi-squared

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R filtering out a subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367120/r-filtering-out-a-subset)

I have an **R** dataset. In this dataset, I wish to create a crosstable using the package `gmodels` for two categorial variables, and then run a `chisq.test` on them.
The two variables are `witness` and `agegroup`. `witness` consists of observations that has value 1,2 and 9. `agegroup` consists of values 1,2. 
I wish to exclude values if `witness=9`, or/and a 3rd variable `EMS=2` from the table but I am not sure how to proceed.

```
library(gmodels)
CrossTable (mydata$witness, mydata$agegroup)
chisq.test (mydata$witness, mydata$agegroup)
```

...so my question is, how can i do the above with the conditions that `witness!=9` and `EMS!=2`

Comment: do you mean how do you subset your data?

Comment: You simply need to subset your data first either using the aptly named `subset()` function in an interactive session, or use the `[` extraction operator. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+subset) search on SO.

Comment: thanks guys. wouldn't subsetting create a new dataset, where those observations are deleted? im interested in something along the if/when/where function in SAS, where it is assigned for each task rather than extracting..

Answer (score 1):

```
 data:
    witness agegroup EMS
    1 1 2
    2 2 2
    1 1 2
    2 1 2
    9 2 2
    2 2 2
    1 2 2
    9 2 2
    2 1 2
 #save the data in your current working directory

 data <- read.table("data", header=TRUE, sep = " ")

 data$witness[data$witness == "9"] <- NA

 mydata <- data[!is.na(data$witness),]

 library("gmodels")

 CrossTable(mydata$witness, mydata$agegroup, chisq=TRUE)
```

You can leave the variable "EMS" in "mydata". It does no harm to your analysis!
HTH

Comment: thanks a lot sathish.. i might not have expressed myself clearly; actually EMS is a variable that has values 1 and 2. I want to exclude the data from the analysis every time EMS has a value of 2 rather than 1

Answer (score 1):

I expect this question to be closed as it really seems like a duplicate.  But as both [Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415635/chase) and [I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317221/user1317221-g) suggested, I think some form of subsetting is the simplest way to go about this, e.g.

```
mydata[mydata$witness !=9 & mydata$EMS !=2,]
```